# ArangoDB Not copying all records

Tags: arangodb

I have a collection called TRANSACTION and I've been trying to copy the collection to a new collection however only 27,000,000 of the 27,763,392 will copy.  I have a unique persistent index on a field called SERIAL and a non-unique index on the POSTING_DATE.  Here is a sample of the records:

```
{
  "SERIAL": 8,
  "STATUS": "P",
  "CATEGORY": "A",
  "PERSON_SERIAL": "NULL",
  "USER_SERIAL": 101,
  "OVERRIDE_USER_SERIAL": "NULL",
  "OVERRIDE_CATEGORY": "S",
  "DEVICE_SERIAL": 104,
  "BRANCH_SERIAL": 1,
  "BATCH_SERIAL": "NULL",
  "SECURITY_SEVERITY": 0,
  "POSTING_DATE": "2019-04-15",
  "POSTING_TIME": "2019-04-15 11:04:28.0"
}
```

The reason I want to copy to a new table is that I cannot create indexes on the existing collection, the system will reset (I assume crash) and restart.  No errors are in the log file (/var/log/arangodb3/arangod.log).  Here is a log entry when the indexing fails:

```
2021-12-17T15:30:17Z [32354] WARNING [66770] {engines} dropping failed index '378294016'
2021-12-17T15:30:17Z [32354] WARNING [66770] {engines} dropping failed index '379036163'
```

I tried to check for duplicates

```
FOR d IN TRANSACTION
    COLLECT serial = d.SERIAL WITH COUNT INTO count
    FILTER count > 1
RETURN { "serial": serial, "count": count }
```

but the system never returns.  I've waited for over 2 days (52 hours) but the query never returns.

Here is my copy AQL command:

```
FOR d in TRANSACTION
   INSERT d INTO TRAN_1 OPTIONS { ignoreErrors: true }
```

Server OS:

- Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS Ubuntu
- Disk 78Gb with 24Gb free
- Memory Total=16424396 Used=12331048 Free=323568 Available3779640
- ArangoDB Enterprise 3.7.16

Any ideas on how to work with large data sets?

Comment: Is this a single server or cluster? Sounds like there are inconsistencies in the underlying RocksDB data, but it is hard to tell from the limited information. Can you try to dump the collection and restore the data into a new collection?

Comment: Yes this is a single server.  I will try and dump the collection and restore.